# Vigenère cipher as an IO filter

Tags: java, io, serialization, vigenere-cipher

I implemented a Vigenere encoding and decoding class. Ideally, the program should be able to take any abritrary file, read into an array of byte, and decode it.

```
import java.io.*;

class VigenereFilterReader extends FilterReader {
    private final char[] key;
    private int i = 0;

    VigenereFilterReader(Reader in, char[] k) {
        super(in);
        key = k.clone();
    }

    VigenereFilterReader(Reader in, String k) {
        super(in);
        key = k.toCharArray().clone();
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        int b1 = super.read();
        int b2 = super.read();

        if (b1 == -1 || b2 == -1)
            return -1;
        int b;
        b = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString((char) b1) + Character.toString((char) b2), 16);

        int out = b ^ key[i];
        i ++;
        i %= key.length;
        return out;
    }

    public String readString() throws Exception {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        int c;
        while ((c = this.read()) != -1) {
            out.append((char) c);
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
}

class VigenereFilterWriter extends FilterWriter {
    private final char[] key;

    VigenereFilterWriter(Writer out, String k) {
        super(out);
        key = k.toCharArray().clone();
    }

    VigenereFilterWriter(Writer out, char[] k) {
        super(out);
        key = k.clone();
    }

    public void write(String s) throws IOException{
        this.write(s.toCharArray());
    }

    public void write(char[] info) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            out.append(String.format("%02X",(info[i] ^ key[i % key.length])));
        }
        super.write(out.toString());
    }
}

class Vigenere {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new Exception("Missing filename");
        }

        String text = "helloworldahelloworld testing a long sequence";
        String key =  "abcdef";

        FileWriter fileEncrypt = new FileWriter(args[0]);
        VigenereFilterWriter encrypt = new VigenereFilterWriter(fileEncrypt, key);

        encrypt.write(text);

        fileEncrypt.close();

        FileReader fileIn = new FileReader(args[0]);
        VigenereFilterReader in = new VigenereFilterReader(fileIn, key);

        System.out.println(in.readString());
    }
}
```

1. This implementation use some casting (line 36, 63 etc). Is the cast dangerous?
2. What is a better way to store encoded byte in file? I used hex string (so that encoded file is readable), but it's quite inconvenient (toHexString at the writer, and when read I have to do 2 read char).

P/S: Here is my updated version using byte IO. Please feel welcome to criticize this code.

```
import java.io.*;

class VigenereFilterInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    private final byte[] key;
    private int index = 0;

    VigenereFilterInputStream(InputStream in, byte[] k) {
        super(in);
        key = k.clone();
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        int c = super.read();

        if (c == -1) 
            return -1;

        int out = c ^ key[index];
        index ++;
        index %= key.length;
        return out;
    }

    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        int result = in.read(b);
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i] = (byte) (b[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class VigenereFilterOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
    private final byte[] key;

    VigenereFilterOutputStream(OutputStream out, byte[] k) {
        super(out);
        key = k.clone();
    }

    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        byte[] out = new byte[b.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            out[i] = (byte) (b[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
        }
        super.write(out);
    }
}

class Vigenere {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new Exception("Missing filename");
        }

        File f = new File(args[0]);

        byte[] text = "hello testing long output!@#)!(!*!(@()asdfasdfljkasdfjlkasdfl".getBytes();
        byte[] key = "hello".getBytes();

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        VigenereFilterOutputStream encrypt = new VigenereFilterOutputStream(os, key);

        encrypt.write(text);

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        VigenereFilterInputStream decrypt = new VigenereFilterInputStream(bis, key);

        bis.mark(text.length);
        int c;
        while((c = decrypt.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }

        System.out.println();

        bis.reset();
        byte[] b = new byte[text.length];
        decrypt.read(b);

        for(byte d: b) {
            System.out.print((char) d);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any byte arrays in your code?

Comment: That's my goal. For now I only know how to use char[]. There's no write(byte[] b) in the FilterWriter class right?

Answer (score 2):

Your `VigenereFilterWriter` doesn't work the way a `Writer` should.  Every call to `write(char[] info)` starts encrypting with the beginning of the key instead of the next character in the key.  That is, I would expect

```
encrypt.write("hello ");
encrypt.write("world");
```

to be equivalent `encrypt.write("hello world");` — but it isn't.  On the other hand, your `VigenereFilterReader` does correctly advance `i` on every successive call to `read()`.

---

The [Vigenère cipher, as described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), involves finding successors within a 26-letter alphabet.  Your XOR variant is quite a bit more complex, though.  Your `VigenereFilterWriter` actually does three things at once:

1. Convert strings to their Unicode code points,
2. Perform XOR,
3. Serialize the result as hex digits.

That's a problematic design.

You're assuming that each character is one byte.  That assumption falls apart for characters like `α` (alpha), which is U+03B1.  If you try to `String.format("%02X", 0x03b1)`, you'll get `3B1`, and your decoder will see `3B` and get out of sync.

The simple solution, and probably the best solution, is to restrict yourself to just the task of performing the XOR encryption.  That is, make a `VigenereFilterInputStream` and `VigenereFilterOutputStream` instead.  You'll need to set up a filter chain to do the job that your current `VigenereWriter` tries to do:

```
OutputStream hexOut = new HexOutputStream(System.out);
OutputStream encrypter = new VigenereFilterOutputStream(hexOut, "mySuperSecretKey".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
Writer encoder = new OutputStreamWriter(encrypter, "ISO-8859-1");
encoder.write("my super secret message");
```

… but at least the responsibility of your `VigenereFilterOutputStream` is clear.  The other tasks, which you currently do incorrectly, can be foisted off on other classes — an [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) for task 1, and a `HexOutputStream` (which you have to write) for task 3.